# Solving a simple systems of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

**Update**:

1) As @Amzoti mentioned, I made a mistake in the mathematica code. There should be spaces between x, y and z. So now the following code works:

```
Solve[{x + y + z == a, xy + yz + xz == b, xyz == c}, {x, y, z}]
```

2) As @Crostul mentioned, this is a standard set of 3rd order Vieta's formulas, so the solution is simply the root of $t^3−at^2+bt−c=0$. I will remove this section once Crostul post an answer and I accept it.

---

I have this equation, which does not seem too complicated for me. Could anyone please explain to me why they are not solved by either sympy or mathematica? Is this set of equation not solvable?

SymPy code:

```
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a, b, c
from sympy import solve

solve([x+y+z-a, x*y+y*z+x*z-b, x*y*z-c], [x, y, z])
```

Mathematica:

```
Solve[{x + y + z == a, xy + yz + xz == b, xyz == c}, {x, y, z}]
```

Thanks!

Shawn

Comment: Why do you say that these equations are "simple"? $x,y,z$ are the three roots of the polynomial $t^3-at^2+bt-c$. Just make your software solve $t^3-at^2+bt-c=0$.

Comment: @Crostul That worked - thank you so much! Could you please briefly explain how you simplified this set of equations down to one single equation?

Comment: I think this can help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: @Amzoti You are totally right! Sorry about my stupid mistake... Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Crostul Thank you so much! You totally solved my problem. Would you like to post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the equation
$$t^3 -at^2+bt-c=0$$
then the three roots must be $x,y,z$ since
$$(t-x)(t-y)(t-z) = t^3- (x+y+z) t^2 + (xy+xz+yz)t - xyz$$